# how using Mutable key in hashamp working in this example?

Tags: java, hashmap, immutability

```
  HashMap hm = new HashMap();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("test");
  hm.put(sb, "second");
  // above code gets hacode for sb and places it corresponding bucket

  sb.append("123");// with appending of "123", sb hascode will change

  System.out.println("element is is" + hm.get(sb));// print "second"
```

Now  hm.get(sb) should search the key in the bucket as per new hashcode. so it should not get any object under
      that bucket and should get null  . So why its getting "second"?

Comment: The output will be value of map i.e second

Comment: You should specify the Key type; `Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>()` would work the way you expect. As is, you're keying on `Object` and `StringBuilder` does not override `hashCode`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The `StringBuilder` class does not override `hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), so it inherits [the `hashCode` method from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).  Therefore, the `StringBuilder'`s contents do not affect the hash code, and even when you change its contents, the `HashMap` is still able to find the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

By default it looks like StringBuilder doesn't use its contents as part of its hashCode(), it just inherits the default hashCode() from Object which uses the memory address as its seed.  So the memory address hasn't changed, thus the key still works.

If you wanted the behavior you expected, override the hashCode method to return

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.toString().hashCode();
}
```

and don't forget to override equals() as well.

Comment: By default I don't know that StringBuilder uses its contents as part of its hashCode().Asking or answering ?